# SQL call - is this correct?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I have recently moved to another host, and I'm incurring a problem. When I input data in my website's form, the database is not updated. However, when the operators of my hosting service do it on their side, the form seems to work for them. Why could this be?

Here is the database call in PHP

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$name = $_POST['name1'];
$surname = $_POST['surname1'];
$email = $_POST['email1'];
$email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL); // Sanitizing E-mail.
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

    define('DB_NAME', 'name');
    define('DB_USER', 'user');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
    define('DB_HOST','localhost');

    $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $name);
    $surname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$surname);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,strtolower($email));

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "INSERT INTO interested (Name, Surname, Email) VALUES ('$name', '$surname', '$email')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Thank you!";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

} else {
    echo "<span>* invalid email *" + $email +"</span>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I mix MySQL APIs in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php)

Comment: Feedback: if someone suggests a possible duplicate, it is not an attack on you. You are welcome to add in an explanation into your question (at the end) about why it is not a duplicate, but focus on the "why" - merely stating it is not a duplicate is insufficient. It is a good idea to refrain from asking your audience to "read the question carefully" - to a native English speaker that is incredibly rude and patronising. I am surprised you did not acquire several downvotes or it. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to mention that you also must activate the error reporting an the mysql level too. E.g. to set the `$mysqliDriver->report_mode`, as below.

So, test this code as it is, after changing the db credentials. If it works, then the problem resided in your codes. If not, then it lies somewhere else.

```
<?php
// Db configs.
define('HOST', 'localhost');
define('PORT', 3306);
define('DATABASE', 'tests');
define('USERNAME', 'root');
define('PASSWORD', 'root');

/*
 * Enable internal report functions. This enables the exception handling,
 * e.g. mysqli will not throw PHP warnings anymore, but mysqli exceptions
 * (mysqli_sql_exception).
 *
 * MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR: Report errors from mysqli function calls.
 * MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT: Throw a mysqli_sql_exception for errors instead of warnings.
 *
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-driver.php
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.constants.php
 */
$mysqliDriver = new mysqli_driver();
$mysqliDriver->report_mode = (MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

// Create a new db connection.
$connection = new mysqli(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE, PORT);

// Signalize if a new record could be inserted, or not.
$recordInserted = FALSE;

// Operations upon form submission.
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // Read the posted values.
    $name = $_POST['name1'] ?? '';
    $surname = $_POST['surname1'] ?? '';
    $email = $_POST['email1'] ?? '';

    // Validate the name.
    if (empty($name)) {
        $errors[] = 'Please provide the name.';
    } /* Other validations here using elseif statements */

    // Validate the surname.
    if (empty($surname)) {
        $errors[] = 'Please provide the surname.';
    } /* Other validations here using elseif statements */

    // Validate the email.
    if (empty($email)) {
        $errors[] = 'Please provide an email address.';
    } elseif (
            !filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL) ||
            !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errors[] = 'The email address is not in a valid format.';
    } /* Other validations here using elseif statements */

    // Insert a new record - if no errors yet.
    if (!isset($errors)) {
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO interested (
                    Name,
                    Surname,
                    Email
                ) VALUES (
                    ?, ?, ?
                )';

        $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
        $statement->bind_param('sss', $name, $surname, $email);
        $statement->execute();

        // Signalize that the new record was successfully inserted.
        $recordInserted = TRUE;
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags must come first in the head -->

        <title>Demo - Insert</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="messages">
            <?php
            if (isset($errors)) {
                echo implode('<br/>', $errors);
            } elseif ($recordInserted) {
                echo 'A new record was successfully inserted.';
            }
            ?>
        </div>

        <br/>

        <form action="" method="post">
            <label for="name1">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name1" name="name1" placeholder="Name" required>
            <br/>
            <label for="surname1">Surname</label>
            <input type="text" id="surname1" name="surname1" placeholder="Surname" required>
            <br/>
            <label for="email1">Email</label>
            <input type="email" id="email1" name="email1" placeholder="Email" required>

            <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
                Submit
            </button>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```